# How to replace the right-most character in a string in sed?

Tags: sed

I have a directory string like:

```
build_result/09_abc_WQVGA_FullTouch_15M.xyz
```

I want to insert the date of the file before the laster `.` character(prefixed with a `_`), so I use the sed like:

```
newname=`echo $filename | sed -n 's/\./\_'"$date"'\./p'`
```

the `$date` has been calculated before the sed command, the result is:

```
build_result/09_abc_WQVGA_FullTouch_15M_20120420.xyz
```

But sometimes there will be some file names like:

```
build_result/09_abc_WQVGA_FullTouch_1.5M.xyz
```

with a extra `.` before the last one, and the sed will insert the `$date` before the first `.`. How to make it only insert the `$date` before the last `.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example like this:

```
date=2012-04-17
echo "demo.txt.foo" | sed -nr 's/(.*)\.([^.]*)/\1_'$date'.\2/p'
demo.txt_2012-04-17.foo
```

If your date contains slashes, you should choose a different delimiter for sed:

```
date=2012/04/17
echo "demo.txt.foo" | sed -nr 's|(.*)\.([^.]*)|\1_'$date'.\2|p'
demo.txt_2012/04/17.foo
```

Since sed tries to match greedy, it will try to capture as much characters as possible, before matching the literal dot. With `[^.]*` you specify 'everything except a dot behind that greedy match.

`sed -r` allows you to omit masking the banana parens.

Answer (score 3):

Others have covered `sed` so I'll proposed to use your shell's capabilities to do that.
Less overhead (spawning subshells..)!

```
$ file='build_result/09_abc_WQVGA_FullTouch_15M.xyz'
$ newfile="${file%.*}_$date.${file##*.}"
$ echo "$newfile"
build_result/09_abc_WQVGA_FullTouch_15M_20120420.xyz
```

using `sed` I'd go with this:

```
sed "s/\(.*[^.]\)\./\1_$date./g"
```

Comment: This is another correct answer! But how to make multiple green-checker? ha!

Comment: I'd go with the shell version. there is no need to echo, spawn a new shell, load the whole environment again and then load sed to do a simple substitution, when the shell itself has that builtin capability.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sed -n 's/\(.*\)\./\1_'"$date"'./p'
```

Comment: don't need to escape the dot or underscore in the replacement part.